# Update statement using select and group by throwing missing expression

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I tried to update a table column `deletiondate` with data from another table but I get "missing expression" error. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Basically I want to update `deletiondate` column in a table by joining the key fields with another table and doing a group by. If the date is `01-JAN-0001` and count of records is > 1 then need to update `01-JAN-0001` else I need to update the maximum deletion date value.

The update Statement I used:

```
update table1 db1 set deletiondate =

SELECT  
CASE WHEN count(*)>1 and ( 
    (select 1 
     from table2 b 
     where b.loginid = a.loginid
         and a.creationdate = b.creationdate 
         and b.deletiondate = '01-JAN-0001'
     ) = 1) THEN '01-JAN-0001' ELSE to_char(MAX(deletiondate),'DD-MON-YYYY') END as deletiondate1  
FROM table2 a 
GROUP BY a.loginid, a.creationdate 
WHERE db1.userloginid = a.loginid and db1.usercreationdate = a.creationdate
```

Comment: No GROUP BY in that SQL, is that as intended?

Comment: @JirkaHanika - The `GROUP BY` was hidden in the code because of bad formatting.

Comment: @NathanSkerl - Looks like an Oracle function to me...

Comment: Oracle does not support `UPDATE ... FROM` you need to change that to a subselect

Answer (score 1):

Use this format: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c46a6/2

```
update product set
  (total_qty,max_qty) = 
(
  select sum(qty) as tot, max(qty) as maxq
  from inv
  where product_id = product.product_id
  group by product_id
) ;
```

Sample data:

```
create table product(
  product_id int primary key,
  product_name varchar(100),
  total_qty int,
  max_qty int
);

create table inv(
  inv_id int primary key,
  product_id int references product(product_id),
  qty int
);


insert into product(product_id,product_name) 
select 1,'KB' from dual
union
select 2, 'MSE' from dual
union
select 3, 'CPU' from dual;

insert into inv(inv_id,product_id,qty)
select 1,1,4 from dual
union
select 2,2,1 from dual
union
select 3,3, 3 from dual
union
select 4,1,1 from dual
union
select 5,2,2 from dual
union
select 6,1,5 from dual;
```

Query output:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | TOTAL_QTY | MAX_QTY |
|------------|--------------|-----------|---------|
|          1 |           KB |        10 |       5 |
|          2 |          MSE |         3 |       2 |
|          3 |          CPU |         3 |       3 |
```

Comment: Hi, what if you want to update 1 column? `total_qty`